# CakePHP: Return every possible result from search if certain search field is left blank

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple search engine in a CakePHP project. One of the searchable fields is set up like this (from my View):

```
echo $this->Form->input('field2', array('label' => 'FieldName', 'multiple' => true, 'div'=>false, 'class' => 'chosen', 'options' => $fromController));
```

The user can select multiple entries from this dropdown, and the selections are returned. This works fine; however, I would like the search to return ALL records based on the value in field1 if field2 is left blank. Is there a way to do that? Here is the Controller code that returns the search results:

```
//Populate the dropdown    
$fromController = $this->Model->find('list', array('fields' => array('field', 'field')));

$requirements = array();
$findOptions['conditions'] = array();

$findOptions['conditions'] = array_merge($findOptions['conditions'], array('Model.field1' => $this->request->data['Model']['field1'],
        'Mode.field2' => $this->request->data['Model']['field2']));

$specificresults = $this->Model->searchOptions($findOptions);
$requirements = array_merge($specificresults);
```

And the function from the Model:

```
function searchOptions($findOptions = array()) {
$records = array();
$findOptions['order'] = array('Model.field1'=>'DESC');

// return the final result....
return $this->find('all', $findOptions);
}
```

Right now, if field1 has a value, but field2 is left blank, nothing is returned. Just need to figure out how to tell the controller that I want everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unset the `field2` condition if it is empty:-

```
if (empty($this->request->data['Model']['field2'])) {
    unset($findOptions['conditions']['Mode.field2'])
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place? I've put it right after $findOptions['conditions'] = array();

Comment: Yep. Answered my own question. Unset should come after I set up $findOptions['conditions']. Working great now. Thanks!